# How to execute all pending scheduled tasks from a ScheduledExecutorService in Java

Tags: java, java-threads, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using ScheduledExecutorService for requeuing events back into a message queue after sometime has passed. Now I need that after some event is triggered all the scheduled pending tasks of this executor are executed.

I have seen that it is possible to cancel the pending tasks, but I need to run all of them before the executor is closed. Is there a way to do this? Or should I use a different strategy to schedule this tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `ExecutorService::shutdownNow`

The object `ScheduledExecutorService` has a method: [`shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()).
It will return a `List<Runnable>` that can be executed.

Comment: Caution: Some implementations of that method will interrupt the currently executing task(s), with their work left undone. Read the Javadoc carefully. I do not believe this achieves the goal of the Question.

Comment: I'll have that into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Or should I use a different strategy to schedule this tasks.

Yes, you should use another strategy.

As the same suggests, a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is for scheduling to run a task after a *certain* amount of time has passed. If you do not know when a task

If you want to buffer some tasks to be executed at a later *undetermined* time, collect your [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects as you would any other bunch of objects. Use a class from the [*Java Collections framework*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

If you care about the tasks being run in a particular order, such as [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) or [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), use a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) or  [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) implementation.

When the time arrives to run your tasks, feed the `Runnable`/`Callable` objects from the queue/deque and submit to an executor service.

- If you care about the *tasks running serially*, and not overlapping their executions in time, then use a [single-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Single_threading) executor service.

  - `ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor​() ;`
- If, instead, you care about getting a bunch of *tasks done as soon as possible*, then you might want to use an executor service backed by a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). This assumes your deployment machine has [multiple cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor), and/or your your tasks are not [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) (the tasks spend significant time waiting on resources such as network calls, reading/writing to storage drives, database queries, etc.).

  - `ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;`
  - `ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​( 4 ) ;`

---

Obligatory tip: Read, re-read, and study the superb book, [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net) by Brian Goetz, et al.